# How to fix the font size in the android app

Tags: android, css, mobile

My android app does not seem to be adhering to the my css style. Changing  the font size in the display panel on the android device affect my display in the app. Basically , if I change the font in the device to large then the text in the android app is large. However, this is not an issue on iOS

Here is style

```
html, body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    font-family: 'Tahoma', 'Helvetica', 'Verdana', 'Arial';
    font-size: 16px;

    }
}
@media (max-height: 600px) {
    html { font-size: 14px; }
}

@media (max-width: 374px) {
    html { font-size: 14px; }
}

@media (max-width: 320px) {
    html { font-size: 12px; }
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: "if I change the font in the device to large then the text in the android app is large" I am confused.  Isn't this what you want to happen?

Comment: Write in `@media () { html, body {}}`, not only `html`

Comment: No, I don't want my app font to resize. So, if the user change the display on the device it should not affect the display in my app. So, what is happening now is if the user change the  font to large then  my layout is messed up. So, it does not seems like the  media query is firing

Comment: Artur.. I tried your suggestion but it did not work... @media () {
   html, body {
   font-size: 16px;
   }
   }